# Having issue with SAP Java connectors

Tags: java, jco

I'm trying to put SAP JCo3 libraries to my work server that has an OS "Win 2003 Server". The SAP JCo3 libraries worked fine on my localhost which has an OS "Windows 7". However when I performed the same procedure for installation on my work server and tried to use the libraries, I've been getting this error:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Error getting the version of the native layer:
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:***********\sapjco3.dll:
>
> This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

Can anyone help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because of Visual 2005 C++ runtime redistributable. The version require by sapjco3.dll should be minimum of 8.0.50727.4053 to work, but however the version on my work server is much lower than this one and lead to this issue. Then I asked my system admin to update it. And now it works.

Answer (score 1):

The sapjco jar depends on the sapjco3.dll native library.

Your local workstation must have that .dll somewhere where java can get at it.

I'd see where the dll is located on your local workstation, and figure out how it's being referenced, then see if you can replicate that on the server.

There are different versions of the .dll for 32-bit and 64-bit windows, so it's possible that you may need a different version on the server than you need on your local workstation.